# Why .htacess is not loading my site after server upgrade?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am working on site which is developed by php and smarty temeplete engine.Everything worked fine before server update.

After migrating my server to **5.4**, firebug is showing the error below  when i access the site.

> **"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://smartflipp.com/"**

I have checked my server error log file, its showing some php warning below :

```
    Illegal string offset 'file_name' in /home/username/public_html/common/configs/config_redirecturl.inc.php on line 79
   Illegal string offset 'normal' in /home/username/public_html/common/configs/config_redirecturl.inc.php on line 85
Illegal string offset 'htaccess' in /home/username/public_html/common/configs/config_redirecturl.inc.php on line 91
   Illegal string offset 'file_name' in /home/smart/public_html/common/configs/config_redirecturl.inc.php on line 79
   Illegal string offset 'normal' in /home/username/public_html/common/configs/config_redirecturl.inc.php on line 85
Illegal string offset 'htaccess' in /home/username/public_html/common/configs/config_redirecturl.inc.php on line 91
Illegal string offset 'file_name' in /home/username/public_html/common/configs/config_redirecturl.inc.php on line 79
Illegal string offset 'normal' in `enter code here`/home/username/public_html/common/configs/config_redirecturl.inc.php on line 85
Illegal string offset 'htaccess' in /home/username/public_html/common/configs/config_redirecturl.inc.php on line 91`enter code here`
<
```

I am giving my .htaccess code :

```
<pre>
RewriteEngine on
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
    FileETag None
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, Public"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
Options -Indexes
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+).html$ $1/?%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^login/$ login.php
RewriteRule ^logincheck/$ loginCheck.php
RewriteRule ^adminlogin/$ adminLogin.php
RewriteRule ^logout/$ logout.php
RewriteRule ^devlogin/$ devLogin.php
RewriteRule ^signup/$ signup.php
RewriteRule ^forgotpassword/$ forgotPassword.php
RewriteRule ^contactus/$ contactUs.php
RewriteRule ^maintenance/$ maintenance.php
RewriteRule ^verify/$ verifyMail.php?%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^help/([^\/]+)/$ helpPage.php?help=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^help/$ helpPage.php?%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^static/([^\/]+)/$ staticPage.php?pg=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^verifypasswordmail/$ verifyPasswordMail.php
RewriteRule ^editprofile/$ editProfile.php4/27/2010
RewriteRule ^rssfeeds/([^\/]+)/$ rssFeeds.php?act=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
#-------Others---------
RewriteRule ^activity/$ activity.php?&%{QUERY_STRING}
#-------flippa urls---------
RewriteRule ^index/$ flips/index.php

RewriteRule ^index/([^\/]+)/$ flips/index.php?list=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^sell/$ flips/addListing.php?action=add&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^edit/([^\/]+)/$ flips/addListing.php?action=edit&list_id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}



#RewriteRule ^listing/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/$ flips/listing.php?list=$1&sortby=$2&sortdir=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^listing/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/$ flips/listing.php?list=$1&filter_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^listing/([^\/]+)/$ flips/listing.php?list=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^viewlist/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/$ flips/viewList.php?title=$1&act=$2&comment_id=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^viewlist/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/$ flips/viewList.php?title=$1&act=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^viewlist/([^\/]+)/$ flips/viewList.php?title=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^golist/([^\/]+)/$ flips/goViewList.php?list_id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^reporting/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/$ flips/reporting.php?type=$1&id=$2&title=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^custom-search/$ flips/saveSearch.php

RewriteRule ^watchlist/$ flips/watchlist.php

RewriteRule ^watchseller/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/$ flips/watchlistSeller.php?act=$1&seller=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^watchseller/$ flips/watchlistSeller.php

RewriteRule ^watchtag/$ flips/watchlistTag.php

RewriteRule ^mybids/$ flips/myBids.php

RewriteRule ^myoffers/$ flips/myOffers.php

RewriteRule ^mylistings/$ flips/myListings.php

RewriteRule ^sale-completion-area/$ flips/saleMessages.php

RewriteRule ^invoice/([^\/]+)/$ flips/invoice.php?type=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^transaction/([^\/]+)/$ flips/transaction.php?invoice=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^trust/([^\/]+)/$ flips/trustManager.php?user=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^trustprofile/$ flips/trustManagerProfile.php?&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^trustphone/$ flips/phoneVerification.php?&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^placebid/([^\/]+)/$ flips/placeBid.php?title=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^buyitnow/([^\/]+)/$ flips/buyitNow.php?title=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^placeoffer/([^\/]+)/$ flips/placeOffer.php?title=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^attachment/([^\/]+)/$ flips/addAttachment.php?title=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^screenshot/([^\/]+)/$ flips/addScreenShot.php?title=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^analytics/([^\/]+)/$ flips/addAnalyticsStats.php?title=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^purchaseupgrades/([^\/]+)/$ flips/purchaseUpgrades.php?title=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^sale-completion/([^\/]+)/$ flips/saleCompletion.php?title=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^escrow/([^\/]+)/$ flips/startEscrow.php?title=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^dispute/([^\/]+)/$ flips/dispute.php?title=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^feedback/([^\/]+)/$ flips/feedback.php?title=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^feedback-for/([^\/]+)/$ flips/feedbackView.php?act=for&user=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^feedback-left/([^\/]+)/$ flips/feedbackView.php?act=left&user=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^paymentsuccess/$ flips/paymentSuccess.php?%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^paymentSuccessVogue/$ flips/paymentSuccessVogue.php?%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^verifysite/([^\/]+)/$ flips/verifySite.php?title=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^verifydomain/([^\/]+)/$ flips/verifyDomain.php?title=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^due-diligence/([^\/]+)/$ flips/dueDiligence.php?title=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^view-copies/([^\/]+)/$ flips/viewCopies.php?title=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^invoices/pay/$ flips/invoicePaymentSuccess.php

RewriteRule ^relistpaymentsuccess/$ flips/relistPaymentSuccess.php?%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^credits/buy/$ flips/buyCredits.php

RewriteRule ^credits/gateways/$ flips/getPaymentGateways.php?%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^credits/withdraw/$ flips/withdrawCredits.php

RewriteRule ^credits/withdrawgateways/$ flips/withdrawgateways.php?%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^withdraw/status/view/$ flips/withdrawStatusList.php

RewriteRule ^success-fee/pay/([^\/]+)/$ flips/successFeePayment.php?title=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^blog/$ flips/blogs.php?%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^blogcomment/(.+)/$ flips/blogComment.php?title=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^pricing/$ flips/pricing.php

RewriteRule ^tags/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/$ flips/tags.php?act=$1&tag_name=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^tags/$ flips/tags.php?%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^siteview/([^\/]+)/$ flips/siteView.php?title=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^whoisdomain/([^\/]+)/$ flips/whoIsDomain.php?title=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
#-------Mail---------

RewriteRule ^mail/compose/$ flips/mailCompose.php

RewriteRule ^mail/inbox/$ flips/mail.php?folder=inbox&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^mail/sent/$ flips/mail.php?folder=sent&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^mail/saved/$ flips/mail.php?folder=saved&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^mail/trash/$ flips/mail.php?folder=trash&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^mail/request/$ flips/mail.php?folder=request&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^mail/sale/$ flips/mail.php?folder=sale&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^readmail/inbox/$ flips/mailRead.php?folder=inbox&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^readmail/sent/$ flips/mailRead.php?folder=sent&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^readmail/saved/$ flips/mailRead.php?folder=saved&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^readmail/trash/$ flips/mailRead.php?folder=trash&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^readmail/request/$ flips/mailRead.php?folder=request&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^readmail/sale/$ flips/mailRead.php?folder=sale&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^selectuser/$ selectUsernames.php

#-------Members---------

RewriteRule ^profile/basic/$ flips/profileBasic.php?%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^profile/avatar/$ flips/profileAvatar.php?%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^profile/personal/$ profilePersonal.php?%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^profile/info/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ profileInfo.php?id=$1&pg=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^profile/password/$ flips/profilePassword.php?%{QUERY_STRING}



RewriteRule ^profile/background/$ profileBackground.php?%{QUERY_STRING}



RewriteRule ^myprofile/$ myProfile.php?%{QUERY_STRING}



RewriteRule ^profilecomments/$ profileComments.php?%{QUERY_STRING}



RewriteRule ^notificationsettings/$ flips/notificationSettings.php?%{QUERY_STRING}



RewriteRule ^editlisting/([^\/]+)/$ flips/editListing.php?title=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}



RewriteRule ^promote/([^\/]+)/$ flips/promoteList.php?title=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}



RewriteRule ^endauction/([^\/]+)/$ flips/endAuction.php?title=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}



RewriteRule ^welcome/$ flips/welcome.php



#------- Site Restricted -----------



RewriteRule ^siteRestricted/$ siteRestricted.php?&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^(support) - [L]

#------ should be last

RewriteRule  ^([^/\.]+)$ flips/profileOverview.php?user=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule  ^([^/\.]+)/$ flips/profileOverview.php?user=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}


#------Js-----

RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
```

**Edited :** 
I am giving the config_redirecturl.inc code's :

```
 /**
 * settings for $CFG
 *
 * ..
 *
 * PHP version 5.0
 *
 * @category    ..
 * @package     ..
 * @author      selvaraj_47ag04
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2008 {@link http://www.agriya.com Agriya Infoway}
 * @license     http://www.agriya.com Agriya Infoway Licence
 * @version     SVN: $Id: config_redirecturl.inc.php 534 2008-04-29 07:42:15Z guruprasad_20ag08 $
 * @since       2008-04-02
 * @filesource
 **/
/**
 * @var             string show login url name
 * @cfg_label       Login url filename
 * @cfg_key         is_login_url_name
 * @cfg_sec_name    login Details
 * @cfg_section     redirecturl_settings
 */
$CFG['auth']['login_url']['file_name'] = 'login';
/**
 * @var             string show login normal
 * @cfg_label       Login url normal
 * @cfg_key         is_login_url_normal
 */
$CFG['auth']['login_url']['normal'] = '';
/**
 * @var             string show login htaccess
 * @cfg_label       Login url htaccess
 * @cfg_key         is_login_url_htaccess
 */
$CFG['auth']['login_url']['htaccess'] = '';
/**
 * @var             string show members url name
 * @cfg_label       Members url filename
 * @cfg_key         is_members_url_normal
 */
$CFG['auth']['members_url']['file_name'] = 'index';
/**
 * @var             string show members normal
 * @cfg_label       Members url normal
 * @cfg_key         is_login_url_members
 */
$CFG['auth']['members_url']['normal'] = '';
/**
 * @var             string show members htaccess
 * @cfg_label       Members url htaccess
 * @cfg_key         is_login_url_htaccess
 */
$CFG['auth']['members_url']['htaccess'] = '';
/**
 * @var             string show first visit url name
 * @cfg_label       First visit url filename
 * @cfg_key         is_first_visit_url
 */
$CFG['auth']['first_visit_url']['file_name'] = 'index';
/**
 * @var             string show first visit normal
 * @cfg_label       First visit url normal
 * @cfg_key         is_first_visit_normal
 */
$CFG['auth']['first_visit_url']['normal'] = '';
/**
 * @var             string show first visit htaccess
 * @cfg_label       First visit url htaccess
 * @cfg_key         is_first_visit_htaccess
 */
$CFG['auth']['first_visit_url']['htaccess'] = '';
/**
 * @var             string show dsabled module url name
 * @cfg_label       Disabled module url filename
 * @cfg_key         is_dsabled_module_url
 */
$CFG['redirect']['dsabled_module_url']['file_name'] = 'index';
/**
 * @var             string show dsabled module url normal
 * @cfg_label       Disabled module url normal
 * @cfg_key         is_dsabled_module_url_normal
 */
$CFG['redirect']['dsabled_module_url']['normal'] = '';
/**
 * @var             string show dsabled module url htaccess
 * @cfg_label       Disabled module url htaccess
 * @cfg_key         is_dsabled_module_url_htaccess
 */
$CFG['redirect']['dsabled_module_url']['htaccess'] = '';
/**
 * @var             string show maintenance module url name
 * @cfg_label       Maintenance module url filename
 * @cfg_key         is_maintenance_module_url
 */
$CFG['redirect']['maintenance_module_url']['file_name'] = 'maintenance';
/**
 * @var             string show maintenance module url normal
 * @cfg_label       Maintenance module url normal
 * @cfg_key         is_maintenance_module_url_normal
 */
$CFG['redirect']['maintenance_module_url']['normal'] = '';
/**
 * @var             string show maintenance module url htaccess
 * @cfg_label       Maintenance module url htaccess
 * @cfg_key         is_maintenance_module_url_htaccess
 */
$CFG['redirect']['maintenance_module_url']['htaccess'] = '';
```

Any idea about how to solve these problem?

Comment: pre putted by mistake. And where should I place RewriteCond? What should I do now to run my site in my server?Thanks for the reply

Comment: Based on the errors you're seeing, the issue is not inside `.htaccess`, but in `config_redirecturl.inc.php`. If you include the contents of `config_redirecturl.inc.php` in your post, somebody might be able to help you.

Comment: You will need to check Apache error.log file not PHP error file for the reason of 500 error

Comment: I have updated the code's , can you please have a look config_redirecturl.inc code's please @Jory Geerts. Thanks

Comment: @anubhava----I have also checked apache error log.It shows some file's are missing like favicon.ico, robots.txt, and devLogin.php. Should I place all those files?

Comment: Also comment out last `RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f` line

Comment: I have placed all the files, still getting the error. Any idea why its happening?

Comment: The error mentions lines 79, 85 and 91, yet what you posted as `config_redirecturl.inc.php` has only 15 lines. Can you include those lines?

Comment: Yes, I have updated my code. please check @Jory Geerts

Comment: `$CFG['redirect']['dsabled_module_url']` is a string instead of an array. If you can figure out where it was defined, you might be able to see what is going wrong. (Dumping its contents at the top of the file should help with that - `var_dump($CFG['redirect']['dsabled_module_url']);`.)

Comment: did not show anything.still getting the error on firebug